# How to style bootstrap aria-expanded attribute with SASS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style the bootstrap 4 `aria-expanded` attribute of the `accordion-header` class with SASS.

Is it possible?

The **HTML** code:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_1" aria-expanded="false">
        Slide Title
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="collapse_1" style="">
        This is the first slide. 
    </div>
</div>
```

The **SASS** code::

```
.accordion{
    .accordion-header{
        position: relative;
        padding: 1rem;

        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;

        &.[aria-expanded="true"]{
          background-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that to target the `aria-expanded` attribute I have just to remove the dot before the selector so I've changed the code from this:

```
&.[aria-expanded="true"]{
  background-color: red;
}
```

to this:

```
&[aria-expanded="true"]{
   background-color: red;
}
```